# Embedding Jetty into dynamic jsp page

Tags: java, jsp, jetty, embedded-jetty

I am very new to Jetty and I am trying to bootstrap it to my web app so that I don't have to use tomcat. Pretty much I have the following file structure:

```
siteapp
   src.main
       java
         com.package
             ConfigHandler.java
             JettyBootstrap.java
       webapp
          WEB-INF
             web.xml
          index.jsp
```

In the JettyBoostraper main method I added this

```
Server server = new Server(8081);

ResourceHandler handler = new ResourceHandler();
handler.setDirectoriesListed(true);
handler.setWelcomeFiles(new String[] {"index.jsp"});

handler.setResourceBase(".");
HandlerList handlers = new HandlerList();
handlers.setHandlers(new Handler[] {handler, new DefaultHandler()});
server.setHandler(handlers);

server.start();
server.join();
```

My index.jsp

```
<%@ page import="com.barcap.edt.atlasrisk.dashboard.ConfigHandler" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
...
...
    <script type="text/javascript">
       <%=ConfigHandler.getConfiguration()%>
    </script>
...

</html>
```

The problem is that ConfigLoader is not loading anything into index.jsp

What could be my problem and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Check out spring boot, it's very quick to get up and running with embedded web containers, such as jetty.
https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/

Comment: Thanks for the comment, however, this does not answer the original post.